# Manifest merger error

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I am getting this error when i build my project

**Here is my error image**

[image: This my error]

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4] /home/nicvaldy/Desktop/android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads/11.0.4/AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads.impl" to force usage

Comment: Read error log carefully and search on google.

Answer (score 0):

change `minSdkVersion` to 14 in your `build.gradle` file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17979222)

Comment: @AK47 answer is related to the problem which is been asked, there is no irrelevant answer on an incorrect answer. Please to consider

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your dependencies

For latest Gradle:
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'

For older one
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'